# Where do consumers for custom built annotations go in my source code?

Tags: java, annotations

I noticed on some tutorials online that code for custom annotations made with the @interface keyword usually does not have any logic. After looking around I found that consumers query the item with that annotation. Here is the link I was looking at:
http://www.objectpartners.com/2010/08/06/how-do-annotations-work/

There is code here to find annotations and act based on what is found. My question is if I made an annotation that prevents using the letter a in the field where would my consumer go? My annotation @interface would just be empty. Where does the consumer go to have this done on compile time, for example?

My understanding of annotations is obviously limited, so hopefully I am asking a clear question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to write an Annotation Processor.

Here is a tutorial. https://blogs.oracle.com/corejavatechtips/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-apis

It's not trivial.

You have to write your own implementation of an `AnnotationProcessor`

```
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_6)
@SupportedAnnotationTypes("*")
public class CodeAnalyzerProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
                          RoundEnvironment roundEnvironment) {
        for (Element e : roundEnvironment.getRootElements()) {
            System.out.println("Element is "+ e.getSimpleName());
            // Add code here to analyze each root element
         }
         return true;
    }
}
```

Then, to use it during compilation, you have to pass the class in as the value to the `-processor` option of javac

```
javac -processor my.project.CodeAnalyzerProcessor TestClass.java
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for the explanation of AnnotationProcessor. I have taken a look at the link you provided and the answers to subsequent questions I have seem to be present there. The help is appreciated.